# Create horizontal scrolling rss in html

Tags: jquery, html, rss, horizontal-scrolling

Is it possible in HTML to scroll horizontally a RSS feed from an external URL?
Can jQuery or Marquee get a RSS input?
If it is possible can someone provide an example code?

Comment: I don't know is it? What have you tried researching? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/
In the feed section it says that "If you want to use a feed from a different domain you'll need to either implement a server-side solution or use something like a JSON proxy".